# Step Function as Custom Connector in AppFlow

Tags: rest, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, amazon-appflow

Wanting to know if you can use a Step Function that calls multiple Lambdas as the source connector in AppFlow.

The objective is to call on a API get request and iterated through the response and based on the response do any number of additional API calls then take the final result and use AppFlow to send it to any of the destinations available with AppFlow.